# How to have curl print the URL that it is fetching?

Tags: command-line, curl

What flags do I need to add to

```
$ curl -o a URI1 -o b URI2 -o c URI3
```

to make it say

```
Getting URI1
Getting URI2
Getting URI3
```

sort of like wget?

No I don't want to need to pipe the output of --verbose etc. through grep, awk, perl, etc. (Yes, --silent gets rid of the timing info. That gets us a little closer to our desired result.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll get with only curl seems to be the `-w` flag:

> -w, --write-out  Use output FORMAT after completion

```
$ curl --silent --show-error -w "Download of %{url} finished" -o a URI1 -o b URI2 -o c URI3
```

To see all of the output control options you can do:

```
curl --help verbose
```

Comment: Cool!  curl --silent --show-error -w 'Got %{url}, Holmes!\n' -o a example.com -o b example.net OUTPUT:
Got example.com, Holmes!
Got example.net, Holmes!

Comment: Ah, great! Thank you for writing back - I was struggling to understand how to make a wildcard example with this. Excellent.